# generate laravel controller without the comments

Tags: laravel

I use `php artisan` to generate controller:

```
php artisan make:controller TestController --resource
```

I always delete the comments because I don't like them, but every time I generate a file I delete the comments and I'm tired of it.

Is there any way to generate files without the comments?

Comment: Copy the generator and the template it uses to your `commands` directory, customize the command `make:cleancontroller` and in the template file just delete the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ohgodwhy's comment indicates, not without creating your own command.

Laravel uses template files to make controllers (and other source files), in the case of a resource controller in Laravel 5.4, this file:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/stubs/controller.stub

The `make:` set of commands generally work by taking a template file and replacing names in them (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Console/GeneratorCommand.php#L152), not with any code generation.
As such, there aren't any options available to change the output (such as indentation preferences).